# In D how do i apply a function to all elements in an array?

Tags: arrays, d

In D how do i apply a function to all elements in an array?

For example i want to apply the `std.string.leftJustify()` function to all elements in a string array.

I know i could use a loop but is there a nice map function? I see there is one in the `std.algorithm` library but i've no idea how to use templates in D yet.

Any examples?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a lot of options to specify the lambda.  `map` returns a range that lazily evaluates as it is consumed.  You can force immediate evaluation using the function `array` from `std.array`.

```cpp
import std.algorithm;
import std.stdio;
import std.string;

void main()
{
    auto x = ["test", "foo", "bar"];
    writeln(x);

    auto lj = map!"a.leftJustify(10)"(x); // using string mixins
    // alternative syntaxes:
    //   auto lj = map!q{a.leftJustify(10)}(x);
    //   auto lj = map!(delegate(a) { return a.leftJustify(10) })(x);
    //   auto lj = map!(a => a.leftJustify(10))(x); available in dmd 2.058
    writeln(lj);
}
```

Comment: keyword "delegate" is optional, so you can write just auto lj = map!((a){ return a.leftJustify(10); })(x);

Comment: I don't believe this does what the OP wants. Here, `x` will remain unchanged. I believe he wants to modify the elements in place.

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to just pass a delegate with ref parameter that changes the element?

Comment: Strings are immutable so unless he chooses to store them in a char[] instead they can't be modified in place.

Answer (score 4):

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    writeln(map!(a => a * 2)([1, 2, 3]));
    writeln(map!(delegate(a) { return a * 2; })([1, 2, 3]));
}
```

Comment: The top one uses the new lambda syntax which won't work until DMD 2.058 comes out.

Comment: I would i use this notation to apply the above string function to all the elements?

Comment: @FredOverflow: It was [on the newsgroup](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/A_nice_way_to_step_into_2012_153482.html).